# Android: unit testing with gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have the following unit test that I can run just fine in android studio, but I am trying to get it set up for continuous integration so I will need gradle to be able to run it.

```
package com.smartsocialmedia.tests;

import android.test.InstrumentationTestCase;

import com.smartsocialmedia.utility.DbConnector;

import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainTest extends InstrumentationTestCase
{
/*
 * Testing DbConnector
 * public JSONObject getJsonObject(ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> params, boolean isGet)
 * pass false as second parameter if GET is to be used rather than POST
 * in this case we are calling auth/login in the API
 */
public void testGETJSONOBJECT() throws Exception {
    //Create an ArrayList of BasicNameValuePair to represent the login information.
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eMail", "myemail"));
    postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password", "mypassword"));
    DbConnector db = new DbConnector("auth/login");

    JSONObject jsonObject = db.getJsonObject(postParams, false);

    //check that the server response is a jsonObject
    assertNotNull(jsonObject);
    //check that we have expected parameters in the response
    int valid = jsonObject.getInt("valid");
    assertEquals(valid, 1);
}
}
```

Basically./gradlew doesn't do anything with this test ... I need to know what I need to change in gradle in order for it to work.

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        // Or, if you prefer, you can continue to check for errors in release builds,
        // but continue the build even when errors are found:
        abortOnError false
    }

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.0.5"
    testPackageName "com.smartsocialmedia.tests"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.1.2@jar'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar')
}
```

Comment: have you tried gradlew connectedAndroidTest?

Comment: What gradle task are you running? connectedCheck will run the tests in /androidTest/ if everything is in place.

Comment: @ed209 did you get this resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least 1.1.0-rc1 (2015/02/02) android gradle plugin

> Unit testing support. Unit testing code is run on the local JVM, against a special version of android.jar that is compatible with popular mocking frameworks (e.g. Mockito).

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Comment: That's just for unit tests running on your local JVM. InstrumentationTestCase is run on device.