# Android Unit testing using gradle

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-gradle-plugin

I want to do unit testing using gradle with out using any device or emulator, below is my code. Its not working, getting error like **Could not find property 'output' on source set unit test** can anybody suggest me how to resolve this.

```
buildscript {

 repositories {
   mavenCentral()
 }

  dependencies {
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11+'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 19
   buildToolsVersion '19.1'

   sourceSets {
     main {
           manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
           java.srcDirs = ['src']
           resources.srcDirs = ['src']
           renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
           res.srcDirs = ['res']
           assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
          }
   }

   dependencies {
     compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
   }

   lintOptions {
      abortOnError true
      textReport true
      textOutput 'stdout'
   }

   sourceSets {
       unitTest {
           java.srcDir file('src/test')
   }
 }

 configurations {
      unitTestCompile.extendsFrom runtime
      unitTestRuntime.extendsFrom unitTestCompile
 }
 dependencies {
      unitTestCompile files("$project.buildDir/classes/release")
      unitTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.8.2'
 }
 task unitTest(type:Test, dependsOn: assemble) {
      description = "run unit tests"
      testClassesDir = android.sourceSets.unitTest.output.classesDir
      classpath = android.sourceSets.unitTest.runtimeClasspath
 }

 check.dependsOn unitTest


}
```

Answer (score 0):

as answered in [Android: unit testing with gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22618356/android-unit-testing-with-gradle/28404132#28404132)

You need to have at least 1.1.0-rc1 (2015/02/02) android gradle plugin

> Unit testing support. Unit testing code is run on the local JVM, against a special version of android.jar that is compatible with popular mocking frameworks (e.g. Mockito).

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system